# trying to upload image to Azure but getting 404

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm trying to upload an image from Server to Azure:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(GLOBAL_AZURE.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
CloudBlobContainer container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("my-container");

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("my-img.jpg");
using (FileStream img = File.Open("d:\...\my-img.jpg",FileMode.Open))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(img);
}
```

Everything works fine until `UploadFromStream` throws:

```
"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
```

`my-container` was created on the Portal and was defined "Public Blob".

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090859/getting-404-error-when-connecting-to-azure-storage-account. Might be worth verifying the container does exist as you expect.

Comment: @AlexS  Container does exist and is found by the code (container parameter displays all sorts of information about the container and everything looks fine). Thank you. Any other idea?

Comment: If the container does not exist in storage the reference `container` in your code will still contain valid properties. Humour me, add the line `container.CreateIfNotExists()` and try it. After that I'm out of ideas as your code is pretty much what I am using myself. Also your code should be `CloudBlobContainer container = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("my-container");` which I assume is a typo in your question else it doesn't compile

Comment: @AlexS I followed your suggestion, and as always the most stubborn bugs are the stupidest ones. Indeed it was a typo in one of the constants holding the container name, hence the 404. Man, sorry for troubling you with this foolish thing. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem at all, we've all been there! Glad your issue is fixed. It's confusing that the container is a populated object when it feels it should throw the error there (like a file not found exception).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused if the container does not exist
See this SO question as well [getting 404 error when connecting to azure storage account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090859/getting-404-error-when-connecting-to-azure-storage-account)

You can ensure the container exists by calling `container.CreateIfNotExists()` prior to uploading the blob.
Personally I run this as part of some application start up code rather than on every blob upload.

This article has background
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#the-client-is-receiving-404-messages

> In the scenario where a client is attempting to insert an object, it
>   may not be immediately obvious why this results in an HTTP 404 (Not
>   found) response given that the client is creating a new object.
>   However, if the client is creating a blob it must be able to find the
>   blob container, if the client is creating a message it must be able to
>   find a queue, and if the client is adding a row it must be able to
>   find the table.